# Running Java in Visual Studio Code gives error "not a statement"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run Java in visual studio code but it gives me this error, it works in IntelliJ though

EDIT:
Okay turns out I would need to make a Main.class file inside of the same file of the Main.java file, with that now it works properly in vscode. But I saw a friend of mine just making one new .java file and it works directly, how can I make vscode to be like so?

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/username/Documents/Java Projects/" && javac Main.java && java Main
Main.java:3: error: not a statement
        System
        ^
Main.java:3: error: ';' expected
        System
              ^
2 errors

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.62 seconds
```

I tried reinstalling Java in Visual Studio Code to no avail
Update: I think I found the problem: Thing is, I tried out Java first with IntelliJ and before that I'd need to make a Java Project. It works through IntelliJ with that new Project file, when I run said Java program in vscode it works as well, but as soon as I make a new file outside of the project file, or a new file outside of the project folder, it gives out a new error which is this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

Comment: Check your environment variables
`CLASSPATH` and `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: @Jilliss how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

`javac main.java && java Main`  into your visual studio code terminal
If the error is the same

then set the temporary environment variable and try `javac main.java && java Main` again

Here is my powershell output

```
PS C:\Users\jilliss> javac Main.java ; java Main
Hello World
PS C:\Users\jilliss> java -version
openjdk version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.6+10 (build 17.0.6+10, mixed mode, sharing)
PS C:\Users\jilliss> cat .\Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
PS C:\Users\jilliss>
PS C:\Users\jilliss> $ENV:JAVA_HOME
D:\win\Scoop\apps\temurin17-jdk\current
PS C:\Users\jilliss> $ENV:CLASS_PATH
PS C:\Users\jilliss> $ENV:CLASSPATH
PS C:\Users\jilliss>
```

As you can see, I only set JAVA_HOME but everything works fine, probably because of your jdk version

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use [*Code Runner*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to execute scripts.** Please use the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack).

[image]

It will be easier to follow the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) to get started.

Comment: This one works, why doesn't Code Runner works though? If I disable Code Runner it should be running properly right? as well as the other programming languages that I use?

Comment: Because coderunner doesn't read your project structure, it just runs script files. If you still use other languages, it is recommended to use the official extensions of the language, such as [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). More information can be obtained in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview).